# How can I create File Instance on nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I need a File instance on Nodejs. I have the file path but my main function accepts  File instance. How can I get a File instance from file path?

```js
// I need a function like that, but it throws an error like `File is not defined`

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * @param {string} filepath
 * @returns {File} 
 */
function getFileFromPath(filepath) {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
  return new File(buffer, path.basename(filepath));
}
```

Comment: There is no "File instance" in node.js. What do you want? Sounds like a xy problem.

Comment: @Marc https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#class-file

Comment: Have you tried to import the buffer module and access the file class? `const {File} = require("buffer");` Why do you expect it its a global defined variable?

Answer (score 0):

According to Node’s `File` constructor signature, it expects a list of `Blob` or similar objects, but not a `Buffer`. You’re giving it a buffer. Try to convert this buffer to a list of blobs, perhaps (e.g. via `[new Blob([Uint8Array.from(yourBuffer)])]`).

Answer (score -1):

I think you implying FileHandle concept.

> A FileHandle object is an object wrapper for a numeric file
> descriptor.

[Detail](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-filehandle)

Code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * @param {string} filepath
 * @returns {FileHandle} 
 */
async function getFileFromPath(filepath) {
  const fileHandle = await fs.promises.open(filepath,'r');
  return fileHandle;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want.